# Obtaining the proper size of a stringstream so I can put it inside a buffer

Tags: c++, boost, stringstream

Here is some sample code

```
std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
oa << newMat;
int size = ss.tellp();
void* matBin = malloc(size);
memcpy(matBin,ss.str().c_str(), size);
```

Basically I am attempting to store some matrices a binary data into a database. This code should turn the matrix into binary data (don't worry about the details of the boost archive), and I am attempting to store the data into a buffer. However, I am not sure if ss.tellp() is the proper way to determine the size of binary data.

Can anyone confirm if this a proper way to determine the size of ss?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `memcpy` in C++? You should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead or maybe [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or at least `new` and [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)). And yes, it's very easy to get the contained "data" from inside those containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
int size = ss.str().size();
```

but I see no reason why tellp wouldn't work as well.